# How to write a program that processes text files and checks the end of a line?

Tags: java, input, output, text-files

I’m trying to write a program that reads all words from the input file and writes the words to the output file sentences.txt. It should start a new line whenever a word ends in a period, question mark, or exclamation mark and if the period, question mark, or exclamation mark is followed by a quotation mark. Otherwise, it separates words with spaces.

My code so far has keeps giving me a long line of output in the middle and doesn’t print a new line out when punctuation marks are followed by quotes. Could someone point me in the right direction? This is what I have so far:

```
  Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.print("Input file: ");
  String inputFileName = console.next();
  String outputFileName = "sentences.txt";

  File inputFile = new File(inputFileName);
  Scanner in = new Scanner(inputFile);
  PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(outputFileName);


  while (in.hasNextLine())
  {  
     String line = in.nextLine();

     if (line.endsWith(".\"") || line.endsWith("!\"") || line.endsWith("?\"") ||
     line.endsWith(".") || line.endsWith("!") || line.endsWith("?"))
     {
        out.println(line);
     }

  }
  out.close();
```

Comment: HINT: what are you doing with `line` when it _doesn't_ end with punctuation or punctuation-quote?

Comment: You’re right, I should put an else statement for that exception. But I’m still getting a long line of code in the middle that connects several lines into one.  Doesn’t seem to recognize that a line is ending with other punctuation marks but the period.

Answer (score 0):

You're testing each line of input to see if it should end a line of output, which doesn't help you much.
You need to test each *word* of input instead.

Here's a simplified version that just reads standard input and writes to standard output:

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Lines {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (in.hasNext()) {
           final String word = in.next();
           if (shouldEndLine(word)) {
                System.out.println(word);
           } else {
                System.out.print(word);
                System.out.print(" ");
           }
        }
    }

    // I hid that big, ugly conditional inside a private method.
    private static boolean shouldEndLine(final String word) {
         return
           word.endsWith(".\"") ||
           word.endsWith("!\"") ||
           word.endsWith("?\"") ||
           word.endsWith(".") ||
           word.endsWith("!") ||
           word.endsWith("?");
    }

}
```

You should probably add logic to print a final newline if needed before exiting.